# How can i call the fetch only when i use onChange in react select?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, onchange, mobx

I recently got headcache with my website was very slow to load. it caused i load 4 data when componentDidMount execute. the problem is.. how can i do the fetch only when i click the onChange?.. i use mobX for state management.. heres my code

componentDidMount :

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.mainStore.getProvinsi();
        this.props.mainStore.getKab();
        this.props.mainStore.getKec();
        this.props.mainStore.getDesa();
    };
```

mobX (one of them) :

```
 @action
    getProvinsi() {
        fetch("api/getprovinsi", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.success) {
                    runInAction(() => {
                        console.log("panggil");
                        this.provinsiData = res.message;
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
```

my onChange :

```
const handleChangeProv = (event) => {
            console.log(event)
            this.setState({ provinsi: event.target.value });
        };
```

and last my react select

```
<Select
                                            labelId="demo-mutiple-chip-label"
                                            id="demo-mutiple-chip"
                                            name="provinsi"
                                            className={classes.widthForm2}
                                            value={provinsi}
                                            onChange={handleChangeProv}
                                            InputProps={{
                                                classes: { input: classes.input },
                                            }}
                                            input={
                                                <Input id="select-multiple-chip" />
                                            }
                                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                                        >
                                            {provinsiData.map((name) => (
                                                <MenuItem
                                                    key={name.id}
                                                    value={name.id}
                                                >
                                                    {name.name}
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </Select>
```

help me

Comment: why are you fetching the data in componentDidMount if you don't want it to be loaded initially?

Comment: i think the data cant be affected to load the data.. but the result, i got the very slow data load

Comment: Add your fetch inside your onChange Event.